# cURL Error - Wordpress W3 Cache

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare, w3-total-cache

I installed the **W3 Total Cache Plugin** on our Wordpress website.

As soon as I check the box “Page Cache” under “General Settings” -> “Debug”, I get the error:

```
.htaccess file contains rules to rewrite url 
https://www.example.com/w3tc_rewrite_test into 
https://www.example.com/?w3tc_rewrite_test which, if handled by 
plugin, return "OK" message. The plugin made a request to https://www.example.com/w3tc_rewrite_test 
but received: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed 
certificate instead of "OK" response.
```

I'm using **Cloudflare + flexible SSL**

Page Cache Method: **Disk - Enhanced**

Minify Cache Method: **Disk**

Comment: I had the same issue on one of my website. My analysis on this was that, the self-signed certificate provided by the cert issuer and the one installed by the hosting provider was not the same. I forwarded my demand to the hosting provider and they happen to resolve this matter within hours. Have you given a try to this?

Comment: How exactly should I do this Sarvesh?